Facing issue with the OG tags - Next.js and Prismic
The OG tags were showing fine for my site but ater updating the Next.js version from
"next": "10.2.0", "next-slicezone": "^0.1.2", to Next 13,
the OG tags have stopped showing. The bizzare thing is that the tags are showing in HTML but not in the source code. Even they aren't showing in opengraph.
I have also updated the Prismic slice machine from  "slice-machine-ui": "^0.0.46" to  "slice-machine-ui": "^2.4.1",
**Initial Prismic Specs - **
"prismic-cli": "^4.2.3", "@prismicio/client": "^5.1.0", "prismic-reactjs": "^1.3.4",
**Upgraded Prismic Specs - **
@prismicio/client": "^7.6.0", "@prismicio/next": "^1.6.0", "@prismicio/react": "^2.8.0",
It would be great if someone can push me in the right direction.
I have tried following solutions -

tried to add tags on a single page
remove dynamic data,
removed all extra configurations from the next config file like web pack
tried to create a static page

